# Query by array value - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in my collection with an array field:

```
location {
[0] = 1.99999
[1] = 3.6544321
}
```

How can I filter by values of array field ?

How can I show only location[0] in find query ?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I show only location[0] in find query ?

Use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to show only the desired element on the array

Sample Documents in a collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231d1bf7e914583df4fbf"), "location" : [ 1.99999, 3.6544321 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231e1bf7e914583df4fc0"), "location" : [ 23.99999, 43.6343341 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231f5bf7e914583df4fc1"), "location" : [ 12.2323, 11.2879731 ] }
```

Mongo Shell Query

```
db.collection_name.find({},{"location":{$slice:[0,1]}});
```

Results

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231d1bf7e914583df4fbf"), "location" : [ 1.99999 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231e1bf7e914583df4fc0"), "location" : [ 23.99999 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231f5bf7e914583df4fc1"), "location" : [ 12.2323 ] }
```

> How can I filter by values of array field ?

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to filter the array elements by values

Mongo Shell query

```
db.collection_name.find({location:{$elemMatch:{$gte:12}}})
```

Results

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231e1bf7e914583df4fc0"), "location" : [ 23.99999, 43.6343341 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3231f5bf7e914583df4fc1"), "location" : [ 12.2323, 11.2879731 ] }
```